# Jquery .attr "disabled" after a few seconds

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I want to disable the start button after 5 seconds but i cant get it to work.
Same with .delay it instantly goes to the disabled mode.
How can i fix it?

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('.start').click(function(){
$('.start').attr("disabled", true); 
});
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got your code inside out.

```
$('.start').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        btn.prop("disabled", true); 
    }, 5000);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/geyucaje/1) *(I changed the 5000 to 500 so you don't have to wait so long)*

Separately, I believe with `disabled` you're better off with `prop` than `attr`.

---

Actually using a bit more jQuery above than I need to, the DOM element is all we need:

```
$('.start').click(function(){
    var btn = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        btn.disabled =  true; 
    }, 5000);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/geyucaje/2)

---

Both of the above assume you want to disable the button five seconds **after clicking it**. If you just want to disable it after five seconds, move the code out of the click handler:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".start").prop("disabled", true);
}, 5000);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/geyucaje/3)

Comment: @user3601328: The first one worked just fine: http://jsbin.com/geyucaje/1 (I changed the 5000 to 500 so you don't have to wait so long). The second one had a typo which I've now fixed, and it works too: http://jsbin.com/geyucaje/2

Comment: mhh for some reason it doesnyt work for me     <script type="text/javascript">
 $('.start').click(function(){
     var btn = this;
     setTimeout(function() {
         btn.disabled =  true; 
     }, 2000);
 });
    </script>

Comment: @user3601328: That'll work *provided* you're running that code after the buttons exist in the DOM, as in my live examples.

Comment: i run that at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.start').prop("disabled", true); 
},5000)
```

Use `prop` when dealing with boolean values.

Comment: this works but as soon as i hit another button on the same page the disabled button is enabled again and than after 5 seconds it disables itself again

Comment: @user3601328: That suggests that the buttons are submitting a form, causing a page refresh.

Comment: Yes it does refresh the page after i click it

Comment: This is what happends i got a start and stop button. when i click the start button it needs to be disabled after a few seconds and when i hit the stop button it needs to disable its self and enable the start button again

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('.start').attr("disabled", true); 
}, 5000);
```

Comment: can you extends more in this, why it will work? and some sample of the code working it will be nice